# Amazon SES vs Node Mailer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

With nodemailer npm, I am able to send email notifications. Found Amazon SES, another transport facility for email notifications. I can push messages using nodemailer and SMTP or can use AWS-SES as transport facility. In both the cases, I am pushing messages from my system.What is advantage of using Amazon SES over nodemailer.

Answer (score 5):

NodeMailer is a utility by using which you can send email but they will not provide the email facility itself.

but AWS SES is a service(SMTP) by which you can send the emails.

You can use Nodemailer with AWS SES.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon SES is like a email service. You can also use Outlook 365 as a email service. NodeMailer is just a utility to send emails. 
Amazon SES has its own API. You could use NodeMailer like utility and configure it with Amazon SES API's to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

NodeMailer requires Node.js while AWS has multi-language API.

Comment: :), I agree with that. However if you see node-mailer documentation, SES is mentioned as transport facility, Why nodemailer again need AWS SES